# NavigatorController is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

**AppDelegate.m**

```
_viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
        nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[_window addSubview:nav.view];
```

**ViewContoller.m**

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navController;
[nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I don't know why the `UINavigationController` always nil.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `navigationController`'s view as `window`'s `subview` try adding `navigationController` as window's `rootViewController`

```
window.rootViewController = nav;
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Just try using  [_window setRootViewController:nav]; instead of window.rootViewController = nav;

Answer (score 0):

**NEW SOLUTION**

try this

in **AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = _navController;

    ViewController* _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_navController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

in **ViewContoller.m** now this will work:

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

**OLD SOLUTION**

try this code

in **AppDelegate.h** be sure to have this at least

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

@end
```

in **AppDelegate.m** at least this

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{}

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize navController=_navController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *_navController = self.window.rootViewController;

    UIViewController* _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_navController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

in **storyboard** be sure to have created a NavigationController binded to a ViewController, defined as initial view controller and binded as root view controller for the binded view controller

in the **app general settings tab** be sure to have set the storyboard in the deployment info section (also in this section you could set status bar style)

in **ViewContoller.m** now this will work:

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

to edit the navigationBar style you can do it this way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
}
```

Comment: _navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; will crash
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController navigationBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103d22720'

Comment: @ManlokWong, corrected my answer, please have a check :)

Comment: crash pushViewController

Comment: [UIViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x115e66320'

Comment: You preferred what controller is assign to rootViewController?

Comment: @ManlokWong, are you sure you are executing my source code? I call push over the navigationController, not on viewController

Comment: Yes. self.window.rootViewController is nil

Comment: @ManlokWong, I updated my answer, I don't know if it will work as I don't know if you have a starting xib or storyboard, you should tell me also what do you have in these files and you organized your project (project file hierarchy at least)

Comment: I have not any xib and storyboard for starting. I only create the UIViewController in code and then set the rootViewController

Comment: is self.window != nil in AppDelegate?

Comment: did you define the "ViewController" class in your project?

Comment: self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Comment: _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
this is my view controller class

Comment: Your solution need storyboard?

Comment: the "new solution" no, try it

Comment: ok, then you should start thinking integrating a main interface xib or a storyboard

Comment: I just integrate the storyboard also see the black screen, but I saw some log which is the ViewContoller function log.

Comment: best suggestion: delete your project and start a new one, flagging that you want a storyboard, then work on what do you want to change, do not start from an empty project, Xcode will do the most you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
homeViewController = (mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("register") as? RegisterViewController)!
let navigationController :UINavigationController = UINavigationController()

navigationController.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: true)
                navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false
                window?.rootViewController = nil
                window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                window?.makeKeyWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @interface AppDelegate ()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
    @end    

//In Your Appdelegate didfinishlaunching method:

     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: YourViewController];
     self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;


     //In Your View controller:
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: self.navigationController is nil too

Comment: This code is working absolutely fine in my case. I guess, there is some issue in your view controller code. Can you check if you have manipulated navigationcontroller stack in your viewcontroller code.